# How do I use C++ vectors with a user defined structure?

Tags: c++, vector, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to manage an array of structures using vectors but keep getting an error msg.

The vector is declared in the header file as:

```
vector< TLE_Values, allocator<TLE_Values> > SavedSatellites;
```

which VS2013 is quite happy with.

The structure is defined as:

```
struct TLE_Values
{
    string CatalogNum;
    string SatelliteName;
    string DateStr;
    string TimeStr;
    string Classification;
    double DecayValue;
    int ElsetNum;
    double InclinationValue;
    double RaanValue;
    double EccentricityValue;
    double ArgPerigeeValue;
    double PerigeeAngle;
    double AvgSpeed;
    double Period;              
    int OrbitNum;
};
```

and initialised with default values by a constructor.

In the main program code, having determined the number of elements I will require ( CountItemsInFile() ), I try to expand the vector list using:

```
SavedSatellites.push_back(CountItemsInFile());
```

This however returns the following compiler error message:

```
error C2664: 
'void std::vector<TLE_Values,std::allocator<TLE_Values>>::push_back(const TLE_Values &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'TLE_Values &&'
1>          Reason: cannot convert from 'int' to 'TLE_Values'
1>          No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous.
```

Another thread suggested that a vector needed to be initialised with 0, which won't happen with a user defined type like this.
What am I missing? where have I gone wrong? How do I create the initial vector with my structure?
There's lots of documentation for using vectors of type (int) but not much if you're not using integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/) are key here:

```
void push_back (const value_type& val);
```

`push_back` doesn't take an `int`, it takes a parameter of the same type your `vector` holds. You need to give it a `TLE_Values` object.

You also don't need to preemptively size the `vector`; you can just keep calling `push_back` until you're done.

Comment: The OP probably wants to `resize()`.

Comment: Agreed, but I don't think they *need* to. It seems they're confused about setting up the `vector` for insertion, and are trying to size it before filling it. Hopefully my edit clarifies that for them.

Comment: @computerfreaker if you know the size you should always resize, otherwise you just waste allocations...

Comment: @BeyelerStudios `push_back` is the wrong insertion method to use in that case, as it always adds an extra element. `resize` followed by `push_back` just wastes space.

Comment: @computerfreaker `push_back` is always wrong when you know the size and `reserve` + `push_back` wastes boundary checks...

Answer (score 3):

To expand a vector use

```
SavedSatellites.resize(CountItemsInFile());
```

If you just want reserve memory for it but keep the size of the vector untouched and ready for subsequent push_back without memory reallocation:

```
SavedSatellites.reserve(CountItemsInFile());
```